# Character count and end with '...' wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am trying to limit my wordpress content to 200 characters and instead of cutting off a word, it only ends the end of of a word and adds a '...' to the end to show there is more to read.

for example:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

gets turned into:

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled...

What I don't want is for it to end like this: and scram...

Can anyone help with this?

Many thanks

Comment: What code are you currently using that's causing this problem?

Comment: Thanks both - MLe - I'm using wordpress' built in function, but thats cuts off a word in the middle.

i have used a str_replace before and that worked, it was just 1 small line of php code, but i can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, where `$input` is plain text only

```
<?php

function chop_string_word($input,$length) {
    if(strlen($input)>$length) {
        $short = substr($input,0,$length-3);
        $space = (substr($input,$length-3,1)==' ') ? $length-3 : strrpos($short,' ');
        return substr($short,0,$space) . '...';
    }
    return $input;
}

echo chop_string_word('Cursus Etiam Parturient Commodo Ipsum Inceptos Elit Magna',25) . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, so how would that work for wordpress the_content(); ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this code where need to display  :

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

**And Add this line of code in function.php**

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');


function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 200;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 200 );
```

Comment: Thank you! - that will change every excerpt on my site though, what if I only want this in 1 area of the website ?